# Popover on <i> elements within a Table

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am trying to get the following behaviour on some font-awesome icons that are being used within a table.

When hover over the icon, shows a popover with more information for the user.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- This file has been downloaded from Bootsnipp.com. Enjoy! -->
    <title>Test Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/search.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/box.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
    </script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/search.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

I thought I'd loaded the script correctly, but there is not the expected response when the file is put live onto the server (I checked bootstrap.js, it does include popover.js and tooltip.js inside of it as code sections.)

in the pastebin below  is a version of the table where I have removed the majority of the rows whilst still keeping it visible what my intention is: http://pastebin.com/hYUBA711

*(didn't want to paste it straight in cause tables always take up a lot of space, even this small 4 rows tall one, the real table is 16 rows)*

Edit: oddly enough, when I try it on jsfiddle it does seem to work as I intend, but the live site doesn't... must be a different issue? The JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zmug2y2q

Comment: post the fiddle please...thanks

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/zmug2y2q](http://jsfiddle.net/zmug2y2q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your jquery code under jquery.js and bootstrap.js:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/search.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    });
</script>
```

Add a **;** at the end of your jquery code: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Ha so as simple a missing close